Get list of last logged users from AD OU
I am trying to get a list of last logged in users using PowerShell.
I tried the following, but doesn't reveal the user:
$ou = "OU=MyOU,DC=test,DC=com"


# Get computers from the specified OU
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties Name, DistinguishedName

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $lastLoggedOnUser = $null
    try {
        $lastLoggedOnUser = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer.Name -ErrorAction Stop).UserName
    } catch {
        $lastLoggedOnUser = "Unable to retrieve"
    }
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $computer.Name
        OU = ($computer.DistinguishedName -split ',',2)[1]
        LastLoggedOnUser = $lastLoggedOnUser
    }
}


Try something like:
# Import the Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Define the OU and domain
$OU = "OU=YourOU,DC=YourDomain,DC=com" # Replace with your OU
$Domain = "YourDomain.com"             # Replace with your domain

# Get all users in the specified OU and their last logon timestamps
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties LastLogonDate | `
    Where-Object { $_.LastLogonDate -ne $null } | `
    Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate | `
    Sort-Object LastLogonDate -Descending | `
    Select-Object -First 10

# Check if users were found
if ($users) {
    # Display the last 10 users to log in
    Write-Host "Last 10 users to log in from the OU: $OU" -ForegroundColor Green
    $users | Format-Table -AutoSize

    # Optionally export the results to a CSV
    $outputPath = "C:\Temp\Last10Logins.csv" # Change path if needed
    $users | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation -Force
    Write-Host "Results exported to $outputPath" -ForegroundColor Yellow
} else {
    Write-Host "No users found in the specified OU or no logon data available." -ForegroundColor Red
}

